# SQL join 3 tables (based on 2 criterias?)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables setup like this (a bit simplified):

time_tracking: id, tr_proj_id, tr_min, tr_type
time_projects: id, project_name
time_tasks: id, task_name

Basically, I want to retrieve either **project_name** or **task_name** based on **tr_type** which can be of value "project" or "task"

An example

**time_tracking**

```
+----+------------+--------+---------+
| id | tr_proj_id | tr_min | tr_type |
+----+------------+--------+---------+
|  1 |          3 |     60 | project |
|  2 |          3 |    360 | task    |
|  3 |          1 |    120 | project |
|  4 |          2 |     30 | project |
|  5 |          2 |     30 | task    |
|  6 |          1 |     90 | task    |
+----+------------+--------+---------+
```

**time_projects**

```
+----+------------------------+
| id |      project_name      |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | Make someone happy     |
|  2 | Start a project        |
|  3 | Jump out of the window |
+----+------------------------+
```

**time_tasks**

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |      task_name      |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | drink a beer        |
|  2 | drink a second beer |
|  3 | drink more          |
+----+---------------------+
```

**Desired output**

```
+----+------------------------+------------+--------+---------+
| id |          name          | tr_proj_id | tr_min | tr_type |
+----+------------------------+------------+--------+---------+
|  1 | Jump out of the window |          3 |     60 | project |
|  2 | drink more             |          3 |    360 | task    |
|  3 | Make someone happy     |          1 |    120 | project |
|  4 | Start a project        |          2 |     30 | project |
|  5 | drink a second beer    |          2 |     30 | task    |
|  6 | drink a beer           |          1 |     90 | task    |
+----+------------------------+------------+--------+---------+
```

And being really bad at the whole JOIN thing, here's the only thing I've come up with so far (which doesn't work..):

```
SELECT tt.tr_proj_id, tt.tr_type, tt.tr_min, pp.project_name, pp.id, ta.task_name, ta.id
FROM time_tracking as tt, time_projects as pp, time_tasks as ta 
WHERE ((tt.tr_type = 'project' AND pp.id = tt.tr_proj_id) OR (tt.tr_type = 'task' AND ta.id = tt.tr_proj_id)) 
AND tt.tr_min > 0
ORDER BY tt.tr_proj_id DESC
```

If anyone has an idea on how to do this, feel free to share!

---

Update: Looks like I forgot to specify that I'm using an **access database**. Which apparently doesn't accept things like `CASE` or `coalesce`.. Apparently there is `IIF()` but I'm not quite sure on how to use it in this case.

Comment: Why this is task ?
`2 | drink more             |          3 |    360 | task`

Comment: Desired output is incomprehensible, where did "Send email" ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan my bad, you're right, I edited to correct the output

Comment: Updated my question, forgot to mention I'm using an access database in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    tt.id,
    CASE WHEN tt.tr_type = 'project' THEN pp.project_name
         WHEN tt.tr_type = 'task' THEN ta.task_name END as name,
    tt.tr_proj_id,
    tt.tr_type,
    tt.tr_min,
FROM time_tracking as tt
   left join time_projects as pp on pp.id = tt.tr_proj_id
   left join time_tasks as ta on ta.id = tt.tr_proj_id
WHERE tt.tr_min > 0
ORDER BY tt.tr_proj_id DESC
```

Comment: Using Access in this case I replaced `CASE` by `IIf()` and it did the trick!  
`SELECT tt.id, IIf([tt.tr_type] = 'project', [pp.project_name],[ta.task_name]) as name, tt.tr_proj_id, etc..`

Answer (score 2):

Use `join` clauses and move your join conditions from the where clause into the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT
    tt.tr_proj_id,
    tt.tr_type,
    tt.tr_min,
    pp.project_name,
    pp.id,
    ta.task_name,
    ta.id
FROM time_tracking as tt
left join time_projects as pp on tt.tr_type = 'project' AND pp.id = tt.tr_proj_id
left join time_tasks as ta on tt.tr_type = 'task' AND ta.id = tt.tr_proj_id
WHERE tt.tr_min > 0
ORDER BY tt.tr_proj_id DESC,tt.tr_day ASC
```

I've used `left join`, which gives you a row from the main table even if one doesn't exist for the join (you get nulls from columns in the joined table if there's no join)

---

A key point here, that many SQL programmers do not realise, is that the `ON` clause may contain any conditions, even ones not from the joined table (as in this example). Many programmers assume that the conditions must be only those relating to the formal foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0):

perform a union on two joins:

```
select tt.id, tp.project_name name, tt.tr_proj_id, tt.tr_min, tt.tr_type
  from time_tracking tt
       inner join time_projects tp on tp.id = tt.tr_proj_id
 where tt.tr_type = 'project'
union all
select tt.id, tp.project_name name, tt.tr_proj_id, tt.tr_min, tt.tr_type
  from time_tracking tt
       inner join time_tasks tk on tk.id = tt.tr_proj_id
 where tt.tr_type = 'task'
```

That will give you the exact table results you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    time_tracking.id,
    time_tracking.tr_min,
    time_tracking.tr_type,
    coalesce(time_projects.project_name, time_tasks.task_name) as name
FROM time_tracking
LEFT OUTER JOIN time_projects on time_projects.id = time_tracking.tr_proj_id AND time_tracking.tr_type = 'project'
LEFT OUTER JOIN time_tasks on time_tasks.id = time_tracking.tr_proj_id AND time_tracking.tr_type = 'task'
WHERE time_tracking.tr_min > 0
ORDER BY time_tracking.id DESC -- ...
```

`coalesce` is MSSQL, there's equivalent `ISNULL` and such in other database technologies

The idea is you join to the tables and if the join fails, you'll get `NULL` where the join failed.  Then you use `COALESCE` to pick out the successful join value.